# Is there a dictionary containing Arabic first and names and their English equivalent?

Tags: data-request, names, dictionary, translation

I have an Arabic and English spreadsheets containing people's information including first and last names.  I have no identifier I can use other than those names, no unique ID or anything.

At the most basic level, I'm looking to see if there's a dictionary containing Arabic first and names and their English equivalent

`"ali": "علي"`

If there are better dictionaries that take into consideration the different ways people write their names, it would be even better

`a["إلياس"] = ["elias", "eli', "elie"]`

But I'm okay with the most basic dictionary, something is better than nothing

Comment: If you have some research or non-profit affiliation, you might be able to request friendly licensing from http://www.cjk.org/cjk/arabic/dan.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there are some commercial databases, but if you are brave and don't need an exhaustive list for 100% coverage, you could use Wikipedia articles for Arabic people

top level : [List_of_Arabic_given_names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arabic_given_names)

mid level : [Abeer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abeer)

bottom level : [Abeer_Hamza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abeer_Hamza)

Other top levels : [Category:Arabic_feminine_given_names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Arabic_feminine_given_names), [Category:Arabic-language_names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Arabic-language_names)

Wikipedia is available as a [dump](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps/Tools_for_importing), so you wouldn't need to scrape. You could also switch back between AR and EN or other languages, which would give you URLs with the person's name

https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B9%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%B1_%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%B2%D8%A9

[image]

---

Actually, a [Wikidata/Sparql](https://query.wikidata.org/) query would probably work, but I can't help much more than that.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44659738/2327328) for getting city names in different languages.

And this *slightly* [modified query](http://tinyurl.com/ycoqq6lx).

[image]

Comment: your solution is so smart, so smart, I'm very impressed

Comment: Glad it is useful. The mapping between identical wikipedia pages in different languages is actually a really valuable resource, because it's carefully curated by humans :)